# Word for Music + Phile?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What would you call someone who loves music? For example, a person who loves books is called a *bibliophile.* Someone who loves movies is called a *cinephile.*

I am trying to write a character description - Matthew, a cinephile, bibliophile and a (word that indicates music-lover and preferably ends in -phile).

Answer (score 5):

The best choice would be:

**melomaniac**

> One with an abnormal fondness of music.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/melomaniac

Answer (score 3):

**Musicophile** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/musicophile); seems close to the meaning.

> *n.* A music lover.

**Audiophile** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/audiophile); is a bit distant though.

> *n. informal* A hi-fi enthusiast.
>
> *"it puts professional studio sound within the reach of the audiophile"*

Comment: The word Audophile is specific to the quality of music one listens to, not the fact that they love music.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stick with *music lover* - it's simple and unpretentious. Using a word ending in *-phile* is fine when it's in common usage, like *bibliophile*, but *musicophile* just feels a little affected.